# Unity3D checking collisions without OnCollisionEnter

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision, raytracing

I'm using gameobjects as bullets in my game, but I probably do it bad. I cast rays from my gun's barrel, instantiate object and move it by Transform.MoveTowards () to a RaycastHit.point. Problem is when I'm shot to an enemy, but it moves before bullet reach it, becauase bullet is floating in air forever. I see two solutions there: I can check if bullet hit someting, but I don't know how because giving hundreds of bullets a script which is done every frame only for OnCollisionEnter is a bad idea. Second way is to changing target position every frame, but I don't know how to save it.
How should I do that?

```
public static List <GameObject> bullets = new List <GameObject> ();
    public static List <Vector3> targets = new List <Vector3> ();

public override void Shot (Vector3 hitPoint) {
for (int i = 0; i < raysNumber; i++) {
            direction = new Vector3 (UnityEngine.Random.Range (-splash, splash), UnityEngine.Random.Range (-splash, splash), 100);
            direction = t_barrel.TransformDirection (direction);
            if (Physics.Raycast (t_barrel.position, direction, out cele[i], 100, layer)) {

                EnemyFPS enemyHealth = cele[i].collider.GetComponent <EnemyFPS> ();
                bullets.Add (MonoBehaviour.Instantiate (g_kubik, t_barrel.position, t_barrel.rotation) as GameObject);
                targets.Add (cele [i].point);


            }
        }

public override void MoveBullets () {
        if (bullets.Count > 150) {
            bullets.RemoveAt (0);
            targets.RemoveAt (0);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < bullets.Count; i++) {

            bullets [i].transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (bullets [i].transform.position, targets [i] * 10, 1f);
        }

    }
```

MoveBullets is called every frame.

Edit: Picture with my problem:
[image]

Bullets:

```
Vector3 pro;
float speed = 10;

void Start () {
    pro = transform.InverseTransformDirection (transform.forward);
}

void Update () {
    transform.Translate (pro * speed * Time.deltaTime);
}

void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other) {
    Debug.Log ("Collision");
    EnemyFPS enemy = other.gameObject.GetComponent <EnemyFPS> ();
    if (enemy != null) {
        enemy.TakeDamage (5);
        other.gameObject.transform.SetParent (other.transform);
    }
    GetComponent<Collider>().gameObject.GetComponent <Collider> ().enabled = false;
    Destroy (gameObject.GetComponent <BulletS> ());
}
```

Shoting

```
t_barrel.LookAt (hitPoint);
MonoBehaviour.Instantiate (g_kubik, t_barrel.position, t_barrel.rotation);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow the Unity3d space shooter tutorial thoroughly I believe all your queries will be solved. Here is the [link](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/space-shooter/boundary?playlist=17147) to it.
What I understand and what you basically need to do is add a collider to your enemy so that when the bullet touches the enemy, something happens. Like, the enemy dies or is injured and ofcourse the bullet gets destroyed, unless it's a sniper rifle bullet which can sometimes penetrate a skull and kill another enemy behind the first enemy, but that is something more advanced.
Alternatively, you could limit the number of bullets that can be spawned per frame.

Comment: I use colliders on my bullets but in this way I must check all objects in my scene or each bullet if it's collide and it's not performance at all. It's 3D game with a lot of models so.
As you can see I have 2 lists now. One is for target positions, target position is where ray from the gun collides with someting on it's end. Bullets list contains gameobject of bullets. And MoveBullets () method move every bullet to target position and it's works fine, each bullet goes tu target position and when it's reach it it's removed from the list. But it's useless if any other objects are moving.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english, but hope you'll understand.

Comment: I really don't understand what are you trying to say. Did you check the link I posted?

Comment: Are you trying to say that if your bullet collides with any object then it is removed which is what you don't want? You only want the bullet to get removed when it hits a target only right?

Comment: I just can't explain. Every bullet i shot is moving every frame to the point. Point is end of the ray from the gun. When bullet reach the point it will stops. Problem is when 400 frames ago in that point was enemy, but enemy is not there now and bullet stops anyway and float in the air forever but it should move forward to a first met collider, than stops. On Collision Enter etc. is not sollution here, because there will be hundred maybe thausand of bullets...

Comment: Ok you could do something like add tags to the collider of enemy and also to a box collider somewhere outside the viewable region.

Comment: Let the bullets move infinitely. In the onColiderEnter compare the tags of first the enemy. If it is true then kill the enemy or decrease health. If not compare with the box collider tag, if it is yes means the bullet missed the target and it should disappear in both the cases. You could simply call Destroy(bulletGameObject) for that bullet.

Comment: Sorry I keep commenting again and again, my thumb is slippery and I press the send key accidentally  on my phone. What I suggested above is already done in the tutorial link I posted. I insist you go through it.

Comment: 1 last thing, I don't think you should be using Rays for this method while it can be simply done with transform and collider. Maybe removing Rays will fix your problem.

Comment: Rays are just for directions.

Comment: So you want to attach one script to all bullets?

Comment: The script that you attach to the main bullet object will replicate itself and work for every bullet object that will be created.

Comment: Do you know what number of FPS will I have if I use 1000 scripts in one scene on my computer?

Comment: As soon as the bullet gets destroyed because of the methods I specified, the script attached to the bullet will stop and get destroyed too, for that bullet object.

Comment: I can just destroy only script. You are right I think. Thanks you. I'll try and will accept your answer.

Comment: Could you move this discussion to chat? StackOverflow suggests.
All you need to do is call Destroy(BulletObjectHere) and the bullet object as well as the script connected to it will get destroyed. Good luck!

Comment: Bullets are not colliding with objects other than player or enemies and go straight the walls like nothing happened. What did I do wrong? Maybe it's work like that because I attached OnCollisionEnter to a bullet and walls are not moving. Is there any way to repair that?

Comment: Please move this discussion to chat as I don't have the required reputation. Also, please post your complete code so I can analyze it.

Comment: I'm just like "I don't know how to do anything on this webstie so I will spam like always here" :/

Comment: When you click on add comment there will be a blue text saying "automatically move this discussion to chat"

Comment: No, there is not :) I see only help or hide help.

Comment: They see me changin'
they hatin'

Comment: I changed almost everything. My only problem now is only shooting direction. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32536467/shoting-object-to-direction

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to add a field to your `BulletScript` named `direction` and have the bullet shoot in a direction other than towards a point. That is why your bullet reaches the point and has no where else to go.

```
public static List <GameObject> bullets = new List <GameObject> ();
public static List <Vector3> targets = new List <Vector3> ();
public float speed;

public override void Shot (Vector3 hitPoint) {
for (int i = 0; i < raysNumber; i++) {
    direction = new Vector3 (UnityEngine.Random.Range (-splash, splash), UnityEngine.Random.Range (-splash, splash), 100);
    direction = t_barrel.TransformDirection (direction);
    if (Physics.Raycast (t_barrel.position, direction, out cele[i], 100, layer)) {

        EnemyFPS enemyHealth = cele[i].collider.GetComponent <EnemyFPS> ();
        BulletScript bullet = Instantiate (g_kubik, t_barrel.position, t_barrel.rotation) as BulletScript;
        bullet.direction = (cele [i].point - t_barrel.position).normalized;
        bullets.Add (bullet);


    }
}

public override void MoveBullets () {
    if (bullets.Count > 150) {
        bullets.RemoveAt (0);
        targets.RemoveAt (0);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < bullets.Count; i++) {

        bullets [i].transform.position += bullets [i].direction * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }

}
```

Comment: Everything is going to be more weird every time. Maybe we just don't really alive. Maybe we are just an imaginations of someones brain, which can handle every moment in our lifes and every our thought.
I don't know if I would use it. Maybe I'll choose second option and I'm going to learn how to check collision with not moving object - if it's possible.

Comment: Because I don't know everything is complicated enought. I'll try, but I don't know if only checking collisions would be easier. Only problem I have using second option is that bullets moving through without activating OnCollisionEnter or OnTriggerEnter.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a tag for your enemy/target in unity itself. For example let us set the tag of enemy game object as "EnemyObj".
Then, use the following pseudo code in the bullets code:

```
void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other) {
//Compare the tag of the Collider other object with "EnemyObj" using compare tag method
//If it is true then..
//Do something like decrease health
//Finally call  Destroy (gameObject.GetComponent <BulletS> ());
}
```

Comment: It'll not solve the problme because OnTriggerEnter is not called if enemy doesn't moves. So checking anything in that function will not have an effect. I'll try do something tomorow, maybe I ruin something very easy.

Comment: If this code is present in the script file of bullets game object then as soon as bullet hits the collider of enemy/any other gameObject, OnTriggerEnter is definitely called.